# Using Prometheus to monitoring AKS ( Azure Kubernetes Service) cannot discover the Kubelet component

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

We are target using Prometheus, alertmanager and Grafana for monitoring AKS but it has been found that cannot obtain the kubelet metrics, I don't know whether it is blackbox/hidden by Azure or not. In addition, container CPU usage i.e. container_cpu_usage_seconds_total cannot obtain in Prometheus. Is anyone have experience on using Prometheus to monitor AKS ?

Remark: I using this https://github.com/camilb/prometheus-kubernetes to install Prometheus on AKS

Answer (score 1):

I assume kubelet is not being detected target to scrape metrics from.
it has to do with your AKS version,
in prior 1.15 versions the metrics-server was started as follow:

- command:

  - /metrics-server
  - --kubelet-port=10255
  - --deprecated-kubelet-completely-insecure=true
  - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,Hostname,InternalDNS,ExternalDNS,ExternalIP

while in recent versions of aks:

- command:

  - /metrics-server
  - --kubelet-insecure-tls
  - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP

Comment: Current we upgrade to AKS 1.17 version and found that cannot detect the kubelet, is anyway to detect it ?

Comment: I'm also very interested to hear this, currently failing to scrape the kubelet in AKS v1.17